# C++ / GameHacking. Не понятна работа приведения указателя

Tags: c++, c, указатели

Указатель - это адрес в памяти, по которому располагается его значение, которое в свою очередь представляет собой другой адрес в памяти.
Я не понимаю одного момента.

1.
Допустим есть какой-то адрес в статическом сегменте памяти, который хранит float.
Мы можем получить значение по этому адресу вот так:

```
float value = *(float*)0xF9F9F9;
```

Тут мне нужно объяснение того, что произошло для дальнейшего понимания.
Мое мнение и предположение: тут мы Си стилем закастили DWORD адрес в указатель на float. То есть теперь по идее, мы создали указатель, который хранит в себе этот адрес. Если мы его разыменуем, то получим значение по этому адресу, то есть как раз то самое float value.

2.
На многих форумах по gamehacking и т.п. я встречаю адрес, который называется указателем.
Вот например:
0xC97C28 - IDirect3DDevice9 pointer

Сразу скажу, что я точно знаю, что это статический указатель. То есть он не меняется в памяти, он в статическом сегменте.

Так вот, я не понимаю одну вещь. Это значение указателя? Или это адрес указателя в памяти?
Если это значение указателя, то по логике это ошибочно, т.к суть указателя как раз в том, что указывать на что-то динамически меняющееся. То есть по моему предположению - это есть адрес указателя в памяти, значением которого является адрес, по которому располагается IDirect3DDevice9.

Тогда, чтобы получить IDirect3DDevice9, мы должны как в прошлом пункте преобразовать этот адрес в указатель, а затем разыменовать.
Тогда начинается бред.
`*(DWORD*)0xC97C28` - в этом случае, мы ведь получаем не IDirect3DDevice9, а значение адреса, по которому он располагается. Т.к мы приняли 0xC97C28 за адрес указателя, а не его значение.

Вторая догадка: допустим 0xC97C28 - это значение указателя. Тогда сделав следующее:

```
*(DWORD*)0xC97C28
```

мы получим IDirect3DDevice9. Но проблема в том, что рушится логика. Если 0xC97C28 - это значение указателя, то это и есть адрес IDirect3DDevice9. Но он динамически меняется, мы не можем его знать.

=> делаю вывод, что 0xC97C28 - это адрес указателя в памяти, и при том этот адрес указателя - статический. А его значение, значение указателя, меняется на динамический адрес, по которому расположен IDirect3DDevice9.

3.
Окей, теперь final question.

```
void **vTable = *(void***)(*(DWORD*)0xC97C28);
```

В таком случае, что это такое? Я это спрашиваю, из-за той проблемы в 2 пункте, ибо я не уверен, что делаем приведение типа указателя: (DWORD*)0xC97C28. Это создает указатель, в значение которого записывает этот адрес, который является адресом указателя уже в памяти приложения. Или это создает указатель, в значение которого записывает этот адрес, который является значение указателя и он же является адресом IDirect3DDevice9.

А дальше вроде я понял так. Т.к для инициализации указателя на указатель мы должны использовать адрес указателя. То мы тут мега-умным способом делаем следующее:
то, что получилось, мы кастим вот таким образом: `*(void***)`
Создаем из того что вышло указатель и для получения адреса этого указателя - создаем два указателя и разыменовываем один, чтобы получить адрес первого.

Жду ваших догадок по поводу приведения типов указателя.
И по поводу того, что имеется в виду, когда показывается какой-то адрес, и говорится, что это указатель.
(этот адрес - это само значение указателя или адрес этого указателя?)

Comment: На какой тип приведёте, тот указатель и будет. `int * * p = * ( int * * * ) 0xee.. ;` или так :  `char * p = * ( char * * ) 0xee.. ;` `T *` - это указатель на `T`. `T * *` - это указатель на `T *`.

Comment: Вы не поняли мой вопрос, либо я его не достаточно хорошо истолковал. Буду ждать каких-либо других ответов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам бы хорошенько перечитать статью про указатели в любом учебнике и решить самостоятельно все примеры оттуда. Во всех ваших рассуждениях есть грубые неточности, которые приводят к тому, что логика разваливается:

**Начнем по порядку:**

```
float value = *(float*)0xF9F9F9;
```

`0xF9F9F9` - это адрес.
Скастовали его в указатель на `float`: получилось `(float*)`.
Теперь вы требуете завести новую переменную `value`, а значение взять, проинтерпретировав 4 байта, начиная от `0xF9F9F9`, как `float`;
**Указатель в явном виде вы не создавали и нигде не запоминали.**

**Второй пример** вы выбрали очень неудачно, в нем много тонкостей, о которые вы и споткнулись:

`DirectX` использует `COM`. В парадигме `COM` практикуются *указатели на указатели*. Таким образом, `0xC97C28` - адрес, по которому сидят 4 байта [0xC97C28, 0xC97C29, 0xC97C2A, 0xC97C2B] (на 32битной венде), хранящие **другой адрес**, который уже указывает на адрес, где лежит адрес ( это уже третий порядок указателя! ), по которому лежит первая инструкция первой функции интерфейса. То есть, чтобы получить точку входа в функцию, нужно сдернуть указатель три раза - отсюда три звездочки в вашем **третьем примере**.

P.S Появление там `DWORD`, кстати, делает программу непереносимой на 64 битную систему.

P.P.S Я очень надеюсь, что сам в этом не запутался. Рекомендую использовать какой-нибудь хороший отладчик типа IDA или GHIDRA, они гораздо нагляднее все показывают, чем я тут написал.

Comment: Спасибо за отличное объяснение! Остались вопросы по поводу второго объяснения, но тут надо разбираться при помощи доп. литературы. Чем я сейчас и займусь.По поводу "Указатель в явном виде вы не создавали и нигде не запоминали.": Да. Но я же могу мысленно представить, что этот адрес, после каста, содержится в каком-то безымянном указателе (вымышленном) и я могу выполнять с ним разные действия, по типу разыменования (интерпретации следующих байт в значение). То есть когда я касчу адрес в (float*), я могу выполнить операцию разыменования, для получения float значений с последующих байтов. Я прав?

Comment: Лучше не заниматься фантазированием, а понимать как есть. Нарисовав перед каким-то значением (float*), вы буквально, физически никакого значения не создали. Вы просто сказали компилятору - там лежит флоат. Все.

Если мой ответ такой "хороший" - где мои лайки?

Comment: Как принятый отметил, а насчёт голоса - у меня еще репка не доросла (ну чтобы публично видно было голос)

Comment: Просьба к поставившему минус - если заметили у меня ошибку (которая возможно есть) - напишите о ней, не сдерживайте себя.